# Memory Management and Tkinter

Tags: python, memory-management, tkinter

I have a question about memory management in Python, specifically pertaining to a program using Tkinter.  First I'll start off with an example I threw together to test some simple memory management:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()
        print("Frame1 created")
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text = "PRESS", command = self.openFrame2)
        btn.pack()

    def __del__(self):
        print("Frame1 destroyed")

    def openFrame2(self):
        self.pack_forget()
        self.destroy()
        frame2 = Frame2(self.parent)

class Frame2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()
        print("Frame2 created")
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text = "CLICK", command = self.openFrame1)
        btn.pack()

    def __del__(self):
        print("Frame2 destroyed")

    def openFrame1(self):
        self.pack_forget
        self.destroy()
        frame1 = Frame1(self.parent)

root = tk.Tk()
program = Frame1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The goal of this program is simple.  Create a Tkinter window containing a Frame with a Button.  When that Button is pressed, delete the Frame, free up any memory taken up by what the frame used, and create a different frame.

If I press the buttons in the order of `PRESS -> CLICK -> PRESS` my expected results are:

```
Frame1 created
PRESS:
Frame1 destroyed
Frame2 created
CLICK:
Frame2 destroyed
Frame1 created
PRESS:
Frame1 destroyed
Frame2 created
```

Instead my actual results are:

```
Frame1 created
PRESS:
Frame2 created
CLICK:
Frame1 created
Frame2 destroyed
PRESS:
Frame2 created
Frame1 destroyed
```

I am a little perplexed here.  `Frame2` seems to properly call the `__del__` method when I call `self.destroy()` however `Frame1` does not.  Why is this?

Comment: Python doesn't guarantee when (or even whether) `__del__()` will be called, it's not C++. Best to forget about trying to use it to do this. Instead think about overloading `destroy()` in your derived classes.

Comment: FWIW: this does nothing: `self.pack_forget`. Even if you called it correctly (`self.pack_forget()`) it's pointless since you delete the widget immediately after.

Comment: You see that's what has me confused, because I am new-ish to Python but know C++.  Would a better option be to create a manual `destroyMe` method that goes over and removes everything the object is using manually?

Comment: For one thing `__del__` won't be called (by the garbage collector, whenever it runs) until all references to the object(s) are gone. It's quite possible that `tkinter` has some internal references that are preventing the memory from being freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change a few things in your code.

First to answer a question you had in a comment:

> Would a better option be to create a manual destroyMe method that goes over and removes everything the object is using manually?

We don't need to use `pack.forget()` because you are destroying the frame.

Use the `.destroy()` method on the container destroys all content within that container. There is no need to destroy everything one at a time. You can use it on a frame that contains multiple frames with their own set of widgets and it will destroy everything in all the frames within the main frame. or you can target just a single widget if you need to.

2nd we don't need `__del__`. Instead just move the print statement after the `self.destroy()` command.

Take a look at the below code. It will print in the expected order you posted on your question while destroying itself in the process.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()
        print("Frame1 created")
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text = "PRESS", command = self.openFrame2)
        btn.pack()

    def openFrame2(self):
        self.destroy()
        print("Frame1 destroyed")
        frame2 = Frame2(root)


class Frame2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()
        print("Frame2 created")
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text = "CLICK", command = self.openFrame1)
        btn.pack()

    def openFrame1(self):
        self.destroy()
        print("Frame2 destroyed")
        frame1 = Frame1(root)


root = tk.Tk()
frame1 = Frame1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the `openFrameX()` methods, why do you assign the result of calling `FrameX(self.parent)` to a local variable (which is immediately thrown away when the function returns)?

Comment: It's not something that would cause the program to noticeably misbehave—just a waste of cpu cycles since it doesn't accomplish anything. Since `.destroy()` might be called from more than once place, it would be better in my opinion to overload it in the derived classes and put the call to `print()` there.

Comment: @martineau Its just part of the OPs original code. I didn't even look at that because I did not run into any errors. I guess I can rework the code to be delete the object instead of a frame. ( fixed type)

Comment: `.desrtoy()` will get rid of everything inside the frame.  Does this include any objects used within the class.  If in the `Frame2` class I create say `self.foo = Bar()`, should i be calling `del self.foo` before the `self.destroy()` to ensure the removal of the `self.foo` object?

Comment: The inherited `.destroy()` knows nothing about other class attributes—however it will "know" about any widgets that are associated with the `tkinter.Frame`. object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @Skitzafreak `self.destroy()` should destroy the class object from my understanding. Also if you try to destroy the class object by name IE `self.foo.destroy()` it will work for the object created outside of the class but for some reason I get an error trying to do that within separate classes. Might have to do with the object not being defined in the global scope.

Comment: @martineau correct me if I am wrong but `self.destroy()` should destroy the entire object of the class right?

Comment: That's what the base class `tkinter.Frame` object method does, but it will have no knowledge of any custom attributes that may have been defined by the subclass (unless it's aware of them because they are `tkinter` widgets attached to it). This means the overridden method in the derived classes should call its superclass method of the same name before or after printing the message.